# How should I unit test this function to avoid business logic and tautologies?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have this function that I am unsure how i should unit test. I've read a bit about not having business logic inside the test function, as well as trying to avoid a tautology in the function

Note: this is python and i'm using the `unittest` library from python

```
SOME_CONSTANT = "constant"

def foo(a, b, c):
  arg1 = "something-{}".format(a)
  arg2 = {
    "p1": b + 1,
    "p2": SOME_CONSTANT,
  }
  arg3 = c
  bar(arg1, arg2, arg3)

def bar(arg1, arg2, arg3):
  pass
```

Assuming `bar` is already unit-tested, i can mock `bar` in my `foo` unit test when i'm testing `foo`.

My current unit test for this looks like this

```
@patch(bar) # this mocks the bar function
def test_foo(mock_bar):
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 3
  foo(a, b, c)

  arg1 = "something-{}".format(a)
  arg2 = {
    "p1": b + 1,
    "p2": SOME_CONSTANT
  }
  arg3 = c
  mock_bar.assert_called_with(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

This doesnt feel right since i am copying logic into the unit test. Is there a better way to unit test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, what you have to test is if `foo` is able to generate the right set of output values - `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3` from the input values - `a`, `b` and `c`.

So, assuming

```
a = 'good'  
b = 9  
c = 'blah'  
SOME_CONSTANT = 9999
```

your unit test would be

```
@patch(bar)
def test_foo(mock_bar):
    foo('good', 9, 'blah')
    mock_bar.assert_called_with('something-good', {"p1": 10, "p2": 9999}, 'blah')
```